# How do I check if values between html tags are blank or empty using regular expressions in notepad plus plus

Tags: html, xml, regex, tags, notepad++

I'm conducting a mass search of files in notepad++ and I need to determine if there are no values between a set of tags (i.e. ).

".*?" will search for 0 or more characters (well, most), which is fine.  But I'm looking for a set of tags with at least one character between them.

".+?" is similar to the above and does work in notepad++.

I tried the following, which was unsuccessful:

```
<author>.{0}?</author>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What went wrong? What was the result?

Comment: I apologize; I believe the expression I posted in the question does work.  I will edit the question.  But I'm looking for the regex to check no values between tags.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you look for something that doesn't exist you don't have to make it that complicated. Simply searching for `<author></author>` would do the trick, wouldn't it? If you want to include space-characters as "nothing" you could modify it to the following:

```
<author>\s*?</author>
```

Output:

```
<author></author>            Match
<author>   </author>         Match
<author>something</author>   No match
```

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, you are right.  No need to be make this complicated.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No need for the lazy modifier on the `\s*`.

Comment: @ridgerunner you're right about that. An old habit to make it lazy :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are using the "?" operator; ".+" should yield the result you need.

Comment: Because the ? operator will prevent the regex engine from being greedy.

Comment: the `?` makes it a lazy search and stops as soon as it finds </author>, else it would match all of following characters.